# Shortest paths between vertices in two sets

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

You're given a directed weighted graph, which has m edges and n vertices. Every edge's weight is nonnegative. The vertices are either in set S1 or in set S2 (*S1 and S2 are disjoint*). You need to find the shortest path between **any pairs** (v1, v2) (v1 is in S1, and v2 in S2).

The running time of the solution should be **O(mlogn)**.

'*Nonnegtive*' and '*mlogn*' remind me of **Dijkstra**, but I have no idea how to use Dijkstra for constant times to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the shortest distance between any v1 in S1 and any v2 in S2, and all edge weights are nonnnegative, the shortest path is just a single edge of smallest weight between a vertex in S1 and a vertex in S2. You can find this in O(m) time from your list of edges.

Comment: @kcsquared if there are nodes in the graph that are not part of `S1` or `S2`, there *may* be no direct edges from one to the other. Also, direct edges, if they exist, *could* be longer than paths through nodes that are neither in `S1` or `S2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijkstra, but modified:

1. Initialize

   ```
   double min = infinite;     // shortest distance between n1 (of s1) and n2 (of s2)
   Node n1 = null, n2 = null; // members of s1 and s2 with shortest distance between them
   Set<Node> visited = new Set<>(); // initially-empty set of visited nodes of s1
   ```
2. Run Dijkstra from each node of s1 *until*

   a. you reach a node of s2 (add start node to `visited`; if `distance < min`, update `min`, `n1` and `n2`)

   b. you reach a node of s1 that is already in `visited` (add the start node to `visited`)

   c. you run out of nodes to visit (possible only if graph is not connected; add the start node to `visited`)
3. Return result pair.

Running Dijkstra is `O(m log n)` worst-case, but you will not be running it fully `|s1|` times - instead, the end result of the above steps is equivalent or faster (in terms of edges visited) to running Dijkstra fully just once per connected component. Therefore, the whole algorithm is `O(m log n)`